# Communication between rclpy client and rlcpp server

Tags: ros, rclcpp, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on converting a ros 1 (noetic) project to ros 2 (foxy). I am on Ubuntu 20.04 I am running into an issue where the python node call the service and the cpp node receives the request and fills out the response. The python node however never receives the response. Any

Here is the function in the python node that calls the service

```
    def _adjust_time(
        self,
        time: rclpy.builtin_interfaces.msg.Time,
        clock_convert: rclpy.client.Client,
    ) -> float:
        """Convert the ROS time to be compatible with the data time."""
        self.get_logger().info("Adjusting time")
        req = TimeConversion.Request()
        req.ros_time = time
        future = clock_convert.call_async(req)
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)
        rclpy.logging.get_logger().info("future complete")
        res = future.result()
        rclpy.logging.get_logger().info(f"Converted time: {res}")
        calendar = res.calendar
        return _calendar_to_seconds(calendar)
```

Here is the cpp node

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "bus_msgs/srv/time_conversion.hpp"

#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>

// Modality enumeration
enum ConversionMode
{
  WALL = 0,
  MIDNIGHT = 1
};

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point start_time;
ConversionMode mode;

/*!
 * \brief Creates a callback to convert a ros::time to a wall clock message
 */
bool conversionCallback(std::shared_ptr<bus_msgs::srv::TimeConversion::Request> req,
                        std::shared_ptr<bus_msgs::srv::TimeConversion::Response> res)
{
  time_t updated_time;  // Time for conversion

  // *** Conversion for midnight mode *** //
  if (mode == ConversionMode::MIDNIGHT)
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("clock_conversion_node"), "Converting to midnight mode");
    // Add the ros time seconds
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point update =
        start_time + std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<1> >(req->ros_time.sec);

    // Extract the time values
    updated_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(update);
  }
  else if (mode == ConversionMode::WALL)
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("clock_conversion_node"), "Converting to wall clock mode");
    updated_time =
        static_cast<time_t>(req->ros_time.sec);  // Note that this assumes time_t implemented as seconds from 1970
  }
  else
  {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "clock_conversion_node::conversionCallback() Unaccounted for mode");
  }

  // Create the response
  struct tm* timeinfo = localtime(&updated_time);
  res->calendar.nanosec = req->ros_time.nanosec;
  res->calendar.sec = timeinfo->tm_sec;
  res->calendar.min = timeinfo->tm_min;
  res->calendar.hour = timeinfo->tm_hour;
  res->calendar.mday = timeinfo->tm_mday;
  res->calendar.mon = timeinfo->tm_mon;
  res->calendar.year = timeinfo->tm_year;
  res->calendar.wday = timeinfo->tm_wday;
  res->calendar.yday = timeinfo->tm_yday;
  res->calendar.isdst = timeinfo->tm_isdst;
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("clock_conversion_node"), "Returning....");
  RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("clock_conversion_node"), "Returning: " << req->ros_time.sec);
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Initialize ros and create a node handle
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("clock_conversion_node");
  // Create parameters for reading in
  int mode_in = static_cast<int>(ConversionMode::WALL);
  int mday_in = 1;    // Day of the month (1-31)
  int mon_in = 2;     // Months since January (0-11)
  int year_in = 122;  // Years since 1900

  // Read in parameters
  if (!node->get_parameter("mode", mode_in))
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Reading in mode from launch file.");
    node->declare_parameter("mode");
    node->get_parameter("mode", mode_in);
  }
  if (!node->get_parameter("start_mday", mday_in))
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Reading in start_mday from launch file.");
    node->declare_parameter("start_mday");
    node->get_parameter("start_mday", mday_in);
  }
  if (!node->get_parameter("start_mon", mon_in))
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Reading in start_mon from launch file.");
    node->declare_parameter("start_mon");
    node->get_parameter("start_mon", mon_in);
  }
  if (!node->get_parameter("start_year", year_in))
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Reading in start_year from launch file.");
    node->declare_parameter("start_year");
    node->get_parameter("start_year", year_in);
  }

  // Make a time value from the inputs
  std::tm t{};
  t.tm_year = year_in;
  t.tm_mon = mon_in;
  t.tm_mday = mday_in;
  t.tm_hour = 0;
  t.tm_min = 0;
  t.tm_sec = 0;

  // Calculate the conversion varlables
  mode = static_cast<ConversionMode>(mode_in);
  start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&t));

  // Advertize the service
  auto service = node->create_service<bus_msgs::srv::TimeConversion>(
      "clock_conversion_manager", std::bind(&conversionCallback, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
  rclcpp::spin(node);
}
```

and here is the output of a launch file that calls the python node

```
[clock_conversion_service-1] [INFO] [1658351829.517198174] [clock_conversion]: Reading in mode from launch file.
[clock_conversion_service-1] [INFO] [1658351829.517288708] [clock_conversion]: Reading in start_mday from launch file.
[clock_conversion_service-1] [INFO] [1658351829.517305416] [clock_conversion]: Reading in start_mon from launch file.
[clock_conversion_service-1] [INFO] [1658351829.517316980] [clock_conversion]: Reading in start_year from launch file.
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351829.715188269] [tpss_manager]: Loading tpss file: /home/tim/bus_ws/install/bus_architecture/share/bus_architecture/config/tpssTest.csv
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351829.719875750] [tpss_manager]: Clock conversion service found.
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351829.720747675] [tpss_manager]: Service clock_conversion_manager available data: [(  0., 150., 20.) (100., 140., 15.) (200., 130., 10.) (300., 120.,  5.)
[tpss_manager_node-2]  (400., 100.,  0.)] adjust_time: <function main.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f8169ef90d0>
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351829.721057999] [tpss_manager]: Creating service
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351842.110816704] [tpss_manager]: Received request for time: [  0. 100. 200. 300. 400.]
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351842.112627908] [tpss_manager]: Received request for power: [150. 140. 130. 120. 100.]
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351842.114431326] [tpss_manager]: Received request for energy: [20. 15. 10.  5.  0.]
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351842.115854425] [tpss_manager]: type of start <class 'builtin_interfaces.msg._time.Time'>
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351842.116857113] [tpss_manager]: Prev: sec: 1 nanoseconds: 0 
[tpss_manager_node-2] type of prevTime: (<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>)
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351842.118233539] [tpss_manager]: Next time sec: 2 nanosec: 0
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351842.119499642] [tpss_manager]: Prev: sec: 2 nanoseconds: 0 
[tpss_manager_node-2] type of prevTime: (<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>)
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351842.120518706] [tpss_manager]: Next time sec: 3 nanosec: 0
[tpss_manager_node-2] [INFO] [1658351842.121612174] [tpss_manager]: Adjusting time
[clock_conversion_service-1] [INFO] [1658351842.122032875] [clock_conversion_node]: Converting to wall clock mode
[clock_conversion_service-1] [INFO] [1658351842.122089857] [clock_conversion_node]: Returning....
[clock_conversion_service-1] [INFO] [1658351842.122115792] [clock_conversion_node]: Returning: 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403999/communication-between-rclpy-client-and-rlcpp-server/) by [asmartbaby](https://answers.ros.org/users/86883/asmartbaby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2022-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I ended up figuring out what the problem was. The python function was nested in the callback of another service. Because I did not specify the callback group they defaulted to the same callback group which was mutually exclusive. I also did not specify a multi threaded executor so multiple callbacks could not be executed at the same time. Here is the article on callback groups if anyone else runs into this problem ([Using Callback groups](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Using-callback-groups.html)).

---

Originally posted by [asmartbaby](https://answers.ros.org/users/86883/asmartbaby/) with karma: 26 on 2022-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zsnafu](https://answers.ros.org/users/101736/zsnafu/) on 2022-09-09**:
Thanks for the link.

Would you be able to post the code that fixed it for you?

Thanks